# Golang get index of inserted value with append

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
list = append(list, Item{})
```

Now I wish to know what index the appended value takes in list. Using len() as following - I am not sure is reliable in case of async code:

```
appendedIndex := len(list) - 1
```

Because by the time the len() function executes, there might have been another value appended to the list.

Must I use Mutex or is there another way?

Comment: Use `map` instead of `slice`.

Comment: if you're in presence of multiple go-routines accessing the same slice we have to lock the moment (or lines) when you write on it (append), for your question we have to see more parts of your code

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski can you please provide an example? I may give you best answer if it works well for me.

Comment: @user1432193 You can ignore my comment. I just learned that `Maps are not safe for concurrent use` :( Your problem as it is formulated cannot be solved without synchronization primitives. From other side, it is good point to check your design and see if you are moving into right direction. Do you really need to share list between several goroutines?

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski Perhaps not. I asked to know if it was possible in general. Would be better if it were.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need some synchronisation, *e.g.* using a Mutex.  This is already true for your `append` statement, since concurrent writes to a slice from different go-routines are not safe.  You can use the same protection for the `append` and for the `len`.  (Maybe you can redesign your code to use channels instead, and have only one go-routine access the actual slice?)

The go race detector warns about problems like this.  If you put the following code into a file, say "ex_test.go":

```
package ex

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

type Item struct{}

func TestAppend(t *testing.T) {
    var list []Item

    n := 2
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            list = append(list, Item{})
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

then a call to `go test -race` warns about a "data race":

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000a4040 by goroutine 8:
  _/Users/voss/Desktop.TestAppend.func1()
      /Users/voss/Desktop/ex_test.go:19 +0x66

Previous write at 0x00c0000a4040 by goroutine 7:
  _/Users/voss/Desktop.TestAppend.func1()
      /Users/voss/Desktop/ex_test.go:19 +0xa7

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  _/Users/voss/Desktop.TestAppend()
      /Users/voss/Desktop/ex_test.go:17 +0xfe
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0x162

Goroutine 7 (finished) created at:
  _/Users/voss/Desktop.TestAppend()
      /Users/voss/Desktop/ex_test.go:17 +0xfe
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0x162
```